# Where am I supposed to store Oauth2 credentials( client_id & client_secret ) for Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

Most of the online tutorials have the client_secret and client_id stored the local environment so I guess that would mean you export it from your .bash_profile for developing on your local computer. Is that correct?

The credentials.json file I downloaded from https://console.cloud.google.com had the XML nested in a web tag which made it difficult to open the local file and json.Unmarshal  for use in local development.

Where should the credentials be stored when I upload to the AppEngine cloud servers?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you want. Do you mean when you deploy an App in GAE? Then AppEngine will use the default service account in your project which is already authorized. You don't need to specify credentials when running an App from the inside. You also can specify manually which service account to use, but it's not needed by default. [More info here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). Is this what you are asking in your question?

Comment: That answers my rambling question.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case, let me post it as a answer. I would appreciate if you accept it in order to guide other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy an App in GAE, it will use the default service account in your project which is already authorized. Therefore, you don't need to specify credentials when running an App from the *inside*. You can also specify manually which service account to use, but it's not needed by default. [More info here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).